# Is it possible to do a svn status on a sibling directory?

Tags: svn, command-line, version-control

Basically when I work on my project, its in the config folder (where gulpfile.js is located, for instance). But my assets folder is on the same level, so when I svn st, of course I cant see any modifications (unless I modify a file in my config directory

```
app
--config (I work from here in CLI)
--src (I work here with less files and such)
```

svn st -> can't see modifications in src folder, unless I change directory in CLI

Comment: You can check statis for parent directory, (ant therefore for config/ and app/) with `svn st ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `status` command takes an optional `PATH` argument (actually: multiple path arguments), with which you can specify arbitrary paths whose svn status should be checked. The supplied path(s) may lie within the current working copy you are working or can be any other working copy on the file system.

By default, `PATH` defaults to `.`, i.e. the current directory you are in. Thus, if you want to see the status of the `src` directory while working in the `config` directory, just run

```
svn status ../src
```